# Camera selects different shutter speed on AV Priority vs Auto

Tags: canon, shutter-speed, aperture-priority

I have a Canon 60D. I've had it for a month now. Today while taking pictures I noticed that if I take a picture in AV Priority, the shutter speed is really slow. So I took a picture in Auto and noted the shutter speed ( 1/60 ), ISO ( 400 ), and aperture ( 4.0 ). Then I switched to AV and on the same shot set my aperture to 4.0 and the ISO was on 400, but the shutter speed was set to 1/6 not 1/60. I uploaded the raws to my computer and reviewed the settings and it seems everything else is the same. Just trying to find a reason for this. My assumption is that the settings to get the proper exposure between modes shouldn't matter - at least between AV and auto - when taking the same shot. I also noticed that something is different in the shot - perhaps the white balance, but that is set on auto as well. Thanks.

- [Auto](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10010684/auto.CR2)
- [AV Priority](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10010684/av_priority.CR2)

So I tried again comparing P and Av.  I had similar results.  I'm on my phone, so these images are from the info screen on the camera.

- [P](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t2s4ww671kqbayg/Photo%20Feb%2014%2C%209%2030%2011%20PM.jpg)
- [Av](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ozddnmygr4gg7k/Photo%20Feb%2014%2C%209%2030%2026%20PM.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easier to compare Program versus Aperture priority because Auto ignores a lot of other settings, most importantly Exposure-Compensation and choice of metering patterns. The ignored settings depends on the camera and I do not have a 60D on hand to check.

Had you changed any of these settings on your camera you would have a large discrepancy.  The other thing is that flash works differently in Auto on plenty of cameras. This may enforce a minimal shutter-speed like 1/60s and ask the flash to fire. While in A mode, the flash wont fire unless the right Flash-mode is set and therefore a lower shutter-speed is required.

To find out what is the case in your setup, do the same comparison between P and A. If those coincide, then you have to try different settings to see which one is ignored in Auto mode.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I compared all the other setting such as flash, exposure compensation, and metering.  I sent the same question to Canon and all they said was I could send it in if I wanted.  I will try what you said with P mode.  I also reviewed the settings in the RAW.  Thanks again.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: @Brian - Puzzling! Did the flash fire in either case? If so, what flash mode is set? Clearly Av is over-exposing and the AWB has not chosen the same color-temperature for both images. One more thing since metering is linked to the AF-mount sometimes, make sure the same focus-point is used (or use MF) to isolate the issue.

Comment: I set the AF point to the center one and the flash fires in both cases.  I may have found something else though.  From reading this ( http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3091680#forum-post-39766222 ) it appears that Av does not take the flash into consideration by default.  They say I can set the flash sync speed but I'll need to look more into it.  I still know very little about photography, so any further insight you could offer on this would be great.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yes. That is why I was asking about the flash. In A mode, the scene is exposed assuming no flash and then flash is added which is why you have an over-exposed scene. This is what is called *Fill* flash and is used to fill out shadows for a bright scene. As I said, the exact behavior depends on the camera.

Comment: Yes, it has to be because of the flash. With flash on with auto settings,  camera sets 1/60th of a second and sets flash output based on the exposure required. That's why setting exposure compensation is not changing shutter speed, only flash output.